# Black layer over reveal modals

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, popup

I have a website with a page which contains three modals (i.e. pop-ups) but only one of them works properly. The other two have a black layer over them which should be in the background.

I have read other threads about similar problems here on this site but nothing has helped so far. I am really confused.

Can anyone help me out a little?

```js
(function($) {

/*---------------------------
 Defaults for Reveal
----------------------------*/
  
/*---------------------------
 Listener for data-reveal-id attributes
----------------------------*/

 $('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
  $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
 });

/*---------------------------
 Extend and Execute
----------------------------*/

    $.fn.reveal = function(options) {
        
        
        var defaults = {  
      animation: 'fadeAndPop', //fade, fadeAndPop, none
      animationspeed: 300, //how fast animtions are
      closeonbackgroundclick: false, //if you click background will modal close?
      dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
     }; 
     
        //Extend dem' options
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 
 
        return this.each(function() {
        
/*---------------------------
 Global Variables
----------------------------*/
         var modal = $(this),
          topMeasure  = parseInt(modal.css('top')),
    topOffset = modal.height() + topMeasure,
            locked = false,
    modalBG = $('.reveal-modal-bg');

/*---------------------------
 Create Modal BG
----------------------------*/
   if(modalBG.length == 0) {
    modalBG = $('<div class="reveal-modal-bg" />').insertAfter(modal);
   }      
     
/*---------------------------
 Open & Close Animations
----------------------------*/
   //Entrance Animations
   modal.bind('reveal:open', function () {
     modalBG.unbind('click.modalEvent');
    $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).unbind('click.modalEvent');
    if(!locked) {
     lockModal();
     if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
      modal.css({'top': $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset, 'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible'});
      modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
      modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
       "top": $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure + 'px',
       "opacity" : 1
      }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());     
     }
     if(options.animation == "fade") {
      modal.css({'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
      modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
      modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
       "opacity" : 1
      }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());     
     } 
     if(options.animation == "none") {
      modal.css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'top':$(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
      modalBG.css({"display":"block"}); 
      unlockModal()    
     }
    }
    modal.unbind('reveal:open');
   });  

   //Closing Animation
   modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
     if(!locked) {
     lockModal();
     if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
      modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
      modal.animate({
       "top":  $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset + 'px',
       "opacity" : 0
      }, options.animationspeed/2, function() {
       modal.css({'top':topMeasure, 'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden'});
       unlockModal();
      });     
     }   
     if(options.animation == "fade") {
      modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
      modal.animate({
       "opacity" : 0
      }, options.animationspeed, function() {
       modal.css({'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
       unlockModal();
      });     
     }   
     if(options.animation == "none") {
      modal.css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
      modalBG.css({'display' : 'none'}); 
     }  
    }
    modal.unbind('reveal:close');
   });     
    
/*---------------------------
 Open and add Closing Listeners
----------------------------*/
         //Open Modal Immediately
     modal.trigger('reveal:open')
   
   //Close Modal Listeners
   var closeButton = $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
     modal.trigger('reveal:close')
   });
   
   if(options.closeonbackgroundclick) {
    modalBG.css({"cursor":"pointer"})
    modalBG.bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
      modal.trigger('reveal:close')
    });
   }
   $('body').keyup(function(e) {
          if(e.which===27){ modal.trigger('reveal:close'); } // 27 is the keycode for the Escape key
   });
   
   
/*---------------------------
 Animations Locks
----------------------------*/
   function unlockModal() { 
    locked = false;
   }
   function lockModal() {
    locked = true;
   } 
   
        });//each call
    }//orbit plugin call
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.reveal-modal-bg {
 text-align:center;
 position: fixed; 
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background: #000;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 z-index: 100;
 display: none;
 top: 0;
 left: 0; 
}

 
.reveal-modal {
 visibility: hidden;
 margin-top:9%;
 left: 31.9%;
 width: 490px;
 background: rgba(250,250,250,0.9) url(modal-gloss.png) no-repeat -200px -80px;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 100;
 padding: 20px 0px 34px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 -box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
  
.col-md-12 send {  
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;  
}
    
.reveal-modal h1 { 
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-family: Raleway Semi-Bold 600, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 150;
}

.reveal-modal h5 { 
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-family: Raleway Bold, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.companyowners { 
 text-align: center;
 display: flex;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

.companyowners > div {
 flex: 1;
}
  
.reveal-modal.small   { width: 200px; margin-left: -140px;}
.reveal-modal.medium  { width: 400px; margin-left: -240px;}
.reveal-modal.large   { width: 600px; margin-left: -340px;}
.reveal-modal.xlarge  { width: 800px; margin-left: -440px;}
 


.close-reveal-modal {
 font-size: 22px;
 line-height: .5;
 position: absolute;
 top: 8px;
 right: 11px;
 color: #aaa;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rbga(0,0,0,.6);
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<div class="popups">
 <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="fade">LINK1</a>
 <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal2" data-animation="fade">LINK2</a>
 <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal3" data-animation="fade">LINK3</a>
</div>
 
 
 
 <div class="reveal-modal-bg">
  <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
  <section class="content margin-top-50 section-bg">
  <div class="container about">
  <div class="row margin-bottom-50 margin-top-50">
  <div class="col-md-6 margin-top-50">

  Popup1
      
        </div>
  </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="reveal-modal-bg">
  <div id="myModal2" class="reveal-modal">
  <section class="content margin-top-50 section-bg">
  <div class="container about">
  <div class="row margin-bottom-50 margin-top-50">
  <div class="col-md-6 margin-top-50">

  Popup2
      
        </div>
  </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="reveal-modal-bg">
  <div id="myModal3" class="reveal-modal">
  <section class="content margin-top-50 section-bg">
  <div class="container about">
  <div class="row margin-bottom-50 margin-top-50">
  <div class="col-md-6 margin-top-50">

  Popup3
      
        </div>
  </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use`<div class = "reveal-modal-bg"></div>`before any modal elements instead of wrapping your modal elements inside of it.  That is what is causing your problems.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

<div class="popups">
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="fade">LINK1</a>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal2" data-animation="fade">LINK2</a>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal3" data-animation="fade">LINK3</a>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal4" data-animation="fade">LINK3</a>   
</div>


//ONLY PUT THIS HERE ONCE//
<div class="reveal-modal-bg"></div>
//.......................//


    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
        <section class="content margin-top-50 section-bg">
            <div class="container about">
                <div class="row margin-bottom-50 margin-top-50">
                    <div class="col-md-6 margin-top-50">

                        Popup1

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>  
    <div class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</div>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal2" class="reveal-modal">
        <section class="content margin-top-50 section-bg">
            <div class="container about">
                <div class="row margin-bottom-50 margin-top-50">
                    <div class="col-md-6 margin-top-50">

                        Popup2

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>  
    <div class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</div>
    </div>


<script src="test.js"></script>
```

Comment: no probs!  could you accept the answer and up vote it for me :)